# how can i clone and erase a row in every row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i can clone the first and the last row but i cant clone the 2, 3, 4 and so on rows, so how can i target this rows to clone and erase them respectively.

now i have to write trash so i can post cause my whatever have too mucho code, really men come on this is not esayflow is it XD

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pkdGW/58/)

```js
$('button[name=add]').on('click', function() {
  var cloned = $('#table1 tr:last').clone(true);

  $('#table1').append(cloned);
})
```

```html
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <select name="numero" id="" class="form-control">
          <option value="">a</option>
          <option value="">b</option>
          <option value="">c</option>
          <option value="">d</option>
          <option value="">e</option>
          <option value="">...</option>
        </select>
        <button name="add">+</button>
        <button name="erase">-</button>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>
        <select name="numero" id="" class="form-control">
          <option value="">1</option>
          <option value="">2</option>
          <option value="">3</option>
          <option value="">4</option>
          <option value="">5</option>
          <option value="">...</option>
        </select>
        <button name="add">+</button>
        <button name="erase">-</button>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you all for taking the time to answer i been playing with your answes and got this, am pretty close to what i want http://jsfiddle.net/pkdGW/59/ which is to put the row under and not beside, if any of you know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If clone does not work properly use "outerHTML" and append it to nearest "tbody".

as follows:

```
$('button[name=add]').on('click', function() {

  var cloned = $(this).closest('tr')[0].outerHTML;

  $(this).closest('tbody').append(cloned);

});
```

For removing row:

```
$('button[name=minus]').on('click', function() {

  $(this).closest('tr').remove();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone the `tr` that has the button you clicked. 
In your code, you are specifying only the last row to be cloned.

So, to clone any other row, target the row containing the button that has been clicked using jQuery `.closest()`

```
$('button[name=add]').on('click', function() {
  // this will select the first tr parent that contain the button
  var cloned = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);

  $('#table1').append(cloned);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `closest()` to clone and remove closest tr.

```js
$('button[name=add]').on('click', function() {
  var cloned = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);
  $('#table1 tbody tr:last').after(cloned);
})
$('button[name=erase]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
})
```

```html
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="2">
      <td class="count">1</td>
      <td>
        <select name="numero" id="" class="form-control">
          <option value="">a</option>
          <option value="">b</option>
          <option value="">c</option>
          <option value="">d</option>
          <option value="">e</option>
          <option value="">...</option>
        </select>
        <button name="add">+</button>
        <button name="erase">-</button>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If table have "tfoot" then " $('#table1 tr:last').after(cloned); " will append row in tfoot not in tbody.

Comment: in that case we can use this`table1 tbody tr:last` ,modified my code, hope it will work now :)

Answer (score 0):

Use remove() function to remove your target.

```js
$('button[name=add]').on('click', function() {
  var cloned = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);

  $('#table1').append(cloned);
})
$('button[name=erase]').on('click', function() {

  $(this).closest('tr').remove();

});
```

```html
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table1">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <select name="numero" id="" class="form-control">
          <option value="">a</option>
          <option value="">b</option>
          <option value="">c</option>
          <option value="">d</option>
          <option value="">e</option>
          <option value="">...</option>
        </select>
        <button name="add">+</button>
        <button name="erase">-</button>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>
        <select name="numero" id="" class="form-control">
          <option value="">1</option>
          <option value="">2</option>
          <option value="">3</option>
          <option value="">4</option>
          <option value="">5</option>
          <option value="">...</option>
        </select>
        <button name="add">+</button>
        <button name="erase">-</button>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```